# Which trait does the given Pedigree chart show?

Tags: genetics, pedigree

I have a doubt in this pedigree chart , according to me it should be autosomal dominant. But the ans given is X linked recessive , in the case of X linked recessive one daughter should be carrier and not affected , but in the chart it's shown the daughter is affected and not a carrier . 
What should be  genotype of female parent ?[image]

Comment: Please do not post questions as photos of text. It discriminates against people using screen readers and cannot be indexed.